# values in the list of dictionary showing None

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of tuple:

```
x = [('router_1', '0/1', '0/4', 'router_2'),
     ('router_1', '0/2', '0/4', 'router_3'),
     ('router_4', '0/1', '0/5', 'router_5'),
     ('router_4', '0/2', '0/5', 'router_6')]
```

the goal is to construct the data as below:

```
dict = {"details": [
        {
            "router_1": {
                "connections": [
                    {
                        "side_a": {
                            "device": "router_1",
                            "interface": "0/47",
                        },
                        "side_b": {
                            "interface": "0/17",
                            "device": "router_2",

                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "side_a": {
                            "device": "router_1",
                            "interface": "0/48",
                        },
                        "side_b": {
                            "interface": "0/17",
                            "device": "router_3",
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "router_4": {
                "connections": [
                    {
                        "side_a": {
                            "device": "router_4",
                            "interface": "0/47",
                        },
                        "side_b": {
                            "interface": "0/17",
                            "device": "router_5",
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "side_a": {
                            "device": "router_4",
                            "interface": "0/48",
                        },
                        "side_b": {
                            "interface": "0/17",
                            "device": "router_6",
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

please note :

- the key router_1 created based on the device name under "side_a"
- the key router_4 created based on the device name under "side_a"

##### I tried below :

```
import collections
data_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)

result = {}

for item in x:
 router_a, router_a_int, router_b_int, router_b = item
 result[side_a] = data_dict["connections"].append({"side_a": {
 "hostname": router_a,
 "interface": router_a_int},
 "side_b": {
 "interface": router_b_int,
 "hostname": router_b
 }})
```

however, The value of the dictionary is showing "None". Looks like everytime append causing the value to be None but I though using  collections.defaultdict(list) should eliminate this issue

Please could you help.

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean is showing None? Be a bit more specific

Comment: `result[side_a] = data_dict["connections"].append(...)` The `.append()` list method  always returns None.

Comment: What is the value of the variable `side_a`?

Comment: `data_dict["connections"].append` will always return `None`

Comment: However, you structure is a mess. Why would you create a list of two dictionaries if you could create one dictionary with two keys? I mean why so overcomplicated.

Comment: What is the logic behind values such as *"interface": "0/47"* ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    x = [('router_1', '0/1', '0/4', 'router_2'),
         ('router_1', '0/2', '0/4', 'router_3'),
         ('router_4', '0/1', '0/5', 'router_5'),
         ('router_4', '0/2', '0/5', 'router_6')]
```

```
    from copy import deepcopy
    
    mDict = dict()
    mDict['details'] = list()
    tmpDict = dict()
    for a, aI, b, bI in x:
        if a not in tmpDict and tmpDict: mDict['details'].append(deepcopy(tmpDict))
        if a not in tmpDict: 
            tmpDict = dict()
            tmpDict[a] = dict({'connections': list()})
        tmpDict[a]['connections'].append(dict({
                                          "side_a": {
                                             "device": a,
                                             "interface": aI,
                                          },
                                          "side_b": {
                                             "interface": bI,
                                              "device": b,
                                          }
                                          })
                                          )
    mDict['details'].append(deepcopy(tmpDict))
```

This will work only if connections in `x` are always sorted.